# generic functions, classes and the "where" keyword

Tags: function, c++-cli, where-clause, generics

how to use "where" keyword to add constraints to a generic class in CLI/C++? I've been searching for a while - but even msdn has only C# documentation!

So the first part of the question is: where to put "where" and what can be written next to it when defining generic classes?

```
   generic <class T> ref class Stack   
   {
      //........
   }
```

Second part of the question is: what does `where T:IComparable` mean in the function definition below?

```
   generic <typename T> where T:IComparable
   T Function(array <T>^ x)
   {
      T max(x[0]);
      for(int i = 1; i < x->Length; i++)
      if(max-> CompareTo(x[i]) < 0)
      max = x[i];
      return max;
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In your example, `where` goes between `generic <class T>` and `ref class Stack`.
2. From [the C++/CLI documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a174071k.aspx):

   > ```
   > where type-parameter: constraint list
   > ```
   >
   > *constraint list* is a comma-separated list of constraint specifications. The list can include interfaces to be implemented by the type parameter.

Answer (score 4):

"generic  where T:IComparable" means that T can only be a derived of IComparable.
So when the user of the generic class tries to use for T a type that's not IComparable the compiler will complain.

As for the first part of the question I have to admit I am ignorant. Maybe a tool like Re-Sharper or CodeRush can help.

Comment: Apears to be a very MS specific solution to me.